# Not sure why this isnt loading content via AJAX in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, wordpress

Creating this simple AJAX Based WordPress theme and Ive created a custom lightbox for it. All is going well but the dreaded IE has now set into play.

For some reason the content isn't loading in IE (only tested IE8).

First off, here's the link to the theme thus far: http://themes.thefinishedbox.com/portfolio/ bare in mind it's still in early stages so will look even worse in IE anyway.

Click the bottom right icon on the image hover.

The class `.postExpand` contains the permalink to the post, while the ID `#postEntry` is what I load via AJAX.

Here's the jQuery for it, if you want a better look you can see the raw file here: http://themes.thefinishedbox.com/portfolio/wp-content/themes/portfolio/js/custom.js

```
$(function() {
    $('.postExpand').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajaxSetup ({  
            cache: false  
        });

        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        var loader = "<div id='loader'></div>"; 
        var loadurl = href + ' #postEntry';

        $('body').prepend('<div id="overlay" />');
        $('#overlay').animate({opacity: 0.8}, 400);

        $('body').prepend('<div id="lightBox" />');

        $('#lightBox').html(loader).load(loadurl, function() {
            $('#postContent').jScrollPane();
            $(this).css({backgroundColor: '#fff'});
        });

        $('#closeBox > div').live('click', function() {
            $('body #lightBox').remove();
            $('body #overlay').animate({opacity: 0}, 400, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });

        $('body #overlay').mouseup(function() {
            $('body #lightBox').remove();
            $(this).animate({opacity: 0}, 400, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });

    });
});
```

I believe the problem lies with the var `loadurl` as I can change that to `'http://themes.thefinishedbox.com/portfolio/'` and it will load.

Anyone have any ideas what the problem may be?

**EDIT**

This doesn't work either:

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
var loadurl = href;
```

Comment: Can you try an `alert(loadurl)` or use the script debugger to figure out the value of loadurl before the load statement?

Comment: Please try to find the value of loadurl and post it here, if it is not the expected one.

Comment: @nfechner the value of load is the permalink (whatever the `.postExpand` links to) also loading the `#postEntry` div within that permalink. There is a reason for that space. Also it doesn't even work in IE with any URL I specify unless it's http://themes.thefinishedbox.com/portfolio/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the permalink structure, possibly a bug with WordPress 3.1 in IE.

It was display /category/ in IE when it shouldn't. Since the theme doesn't require categories I stripped the permalink structure to just /%POSTNAME%/ and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your loadurl statement has a space too many:

```
var loadurl = href + ' #postEntry';
```

versus

```
var loadurl = href + '#postEntry';
```